# How to express “Cela comptera moins”? (What are the most important objectives and those that'll count less)

Tags: translation, french

In the French sentence:

> Quels sont les objectifs les plus importants et ceux qui compteront moins ?

That I can approximately translate into:

> What are the most important objectives and those that'll count less?

I'm quite sure that the translation `count less` is quite inappropriate or at least weird for English natives, isn't it?

How should I translate it? I want to ask in my question what are the most important goals, and what are those that'll be the least important, that'll "count less", that'll matter less.

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, I'm not quite sure what the sentence is trying to say. Is the following accurate? *What are those objectives that are the most important and those objectives that are not?* (In short, if that interpretation is correct, it's just a fancy way of asking for all of the objectives.)

Comment: @JasonBassford My sentence wanted to ask for the best objectives and the worst, those "in the middle" are not wanted :)

Comment: What's wrong with "The most important, and those that count for less"?

Answer (score 1):

There are various options, depending on the context in which the phrase is being used. Literally, "cela compera moins" translates to to something like "that's not so important" - which might be appropriate. But the implicit meaning given in the question suggests constructions like "that should not be our priority" (when planning some course of action eg in business) or "that has less impact" when comparing outcomes.

> I want to ask in my question what are the most important goals, and what 
>   are those that'll be the least important

Why not ask "which are our most important goals, and which are lower priority/will have less impact"? Of course, that's a bit wordier than "cela compera moins".

Answer (score 0):

From a comment that was under the question:

> My sentence wanted to ask for the best objectives and the worst, those "in the middle" are not wanted :)

In that case, a paraphrased translation would be preferable to a literal one. (Like many translations, it's better if it's not just word for word.)

Something like this would work:

> What are the objectives that are the most and least important?